# $|x|^k= \sum\limits_{|\gamma |=k} |x^{\gamma}|$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Let $x=(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb R^2.$ Let $\gamma =(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ where $\gamma_i \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}.$ Put $|\gamma| = \gamma_1 +\gamma_2$ and $x^{\gamma}= x^{\gamma_1}_1 x_{2}^{\gamma_2}.$

> Question: Let $k\in \mathbb N.$ Can we say $|x|^k \leq \sum\limits_{|\gamma |=k} |x^{\gamma}|$? Can we say $|x|^k= \sum\limits_{|\gamma |=k} |x^{\gamma}|$?

Comment: For $k = 2$, we have $|x|^2 = |x_1|^2+|x_2|^2$ and $$\sum_{|\gamma| = 2}|x^\gamma| = |x_1^2\cdot 1| + |x_1x_2| + |1\cdot x_2^2|$$
which means at the very least that we do not have equality in general (although there are cases where they are equal).

Answer (score 1):

Define the map $x\rightarrow\displaystyle\sum_{|\gamma|=k}\left|x^{\gamma}\right|$ on ${\bf{S}}^{n-1}$, then it is continuous, so it attains the minimum value, say, $c_{k}>0$, then for all $x\ne 0$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{|\gamma|=k}\left|\dfrac{x^{\gamma}}{|x|^{|\gamma|}}\right|=\displaystyle\sum_{|\gamma|=k}\left|\dfrac{x^{\gamma}}{|x|^{k}}\right|\geq c_{k}$, so $|x|^{k}\leq\dfrac{1}{c_{k}}\displaystyle\sum_{|\gamma|=k}\left|x^{\gamma}\right|$, this is what we can conclude about.